# How can we Implement a c++ class such that it allows us to add data members at runtime

Tags: c++

How can we Implement a c++ class such that it allows us to add data members at runtime. This question was asked in an interview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find that to be a quite interesting interview question. If I was asking it, I would hope for that to be a starter of a back and forth conversation. The interviewed would have to know that you *cannot* add members dynamically, but I would hope for questions about the actual problem to solve (*what do you want to solve? why do you need to add members?*) and proposed solutions that would tackle those situations.

Note that there are two ways of looking to an interview question, looking for facts and looking for problem solving abilities. This is one question where both of them can be exercised (then again, it is up to the interviewer to lead the conversation, i.e. if the person just answers *it's impossible*, the interviewer can continue as *but I need to be able to...*)

Comment: Perfect answer for this kind of question. +1

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that in C++, there's not many languages you could do it in. You could have some sort of simulation of that with maps and such like but it's not the same thing.

I hope you just answered no.

Comment: But his question was to simulate such a behavior.

Comment: @pkvprakash: You didn't say that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you cannot change the class vtable at runtime - that's be silly, but you can use a single member variable that allows you to add entries to it, a stl map would be a good choice here.

As a map store name-value pairs, you would use it to store data comprising of the 'data member' name and the corresponding data value.

I hope you asked "what do you mean?" to that interview question and got them to explain just what they were thinking.

Comment: "Obviously you cannot change the class vtable at runtime - that's be silly" As the author of a mocking framework that does exactly this, LOL. Not recommended for regular software though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add data members in C++. You should look into containers for C++, perhaps the http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/ which allows you to tag data with names.